# Ruby Rails: Passing a text box value to the Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Ruby Rails, I want to display a text box where you enter a value, with a button beside it to perform a search based on what you typed into the text box. My code:

```
<%= number_field_tag :user_search_id, params[:user_search_id] %>

<%= button_to 'Search by user id', {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"search", :user_id => params[:user_search_id]} %>
```

However, no matter whats typed into the text box, its never placed in the params hash, and I end up passing nothing to the controller.

Here is the controller code:

```
def search

@post = Post.find(params[:user_id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
    format.json { render json: @post }
  end

  #redirect_to posts_url

end
```

Note I have attempted to pass both :user_id and :user_search_id, neither passes correctly. However, if I pass a literal (the number 1), it passes correctly, so it just looks like the :user_search_id value is never getting associated with that key.

Answer (score 1):

you need a form...

```
<%= form_tag({:controller=>"posts", :action=>"search"}, method: :get) do %>
  <%= number_field_tag :user_search_id %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search by user id', name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

In your controller you can use:

```
params[:user_search_id]
```

**EDIT** - using the above form, you will be able to access the `params[:user_search_id]` in your controller. Now you can use `where` to find the correct post.

```
@post = Post.where(:id => params[:user_search_id])
```

Comment: No dice - same problem, the controller sees nothing for that param hash tag. Confirmed by passing it to a local variable, which reports nil for content. Do I somehow need to register the contents of the text box by moving to a new page before I can use it?

Comment: where are you trying to use the `params[:user_search_id]`? It should be in the controller posts, action search. Please include the controller in your question. Also, you should be able to see the search in the url.

Comment: Using the user_search_id to allow the user to search by a key. Passing a literal works, I just can't get whats in the text box. Appended my original post with the controller code.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you how to use the `params[:user_search_id]` in your controller. I hope it helps.

Comment: @user2062016 if the answer solved your problem can you please share and accept the answer? Thanks!